# Definition of a modular form and a survey of the main examples

Tags: modular-forms

I am trying to solve the following exercise:

Let  k $\in \mathbb {Z} $ and $f: \mathbb{H}\longrightarrow \mathbb {C} $ be a holomorphic function with
$f \mid_k\gamma = f$
for all
$\gamma \in\Gamma_1$
and
$$f(x+iy) = O(1)    (y \rightarrow+\infty).$$
show: for all $x\in \mathbb {Q} $ the following holds
$$f(x+iy)= O(y^{(-k)})   (y\downarrow 0)$$
hint: show
$f(\frac{a}{c}+iy)=({\frac{i}{c}})^k y^{-k} f(-\frac{d}{c}+\frac{i}{c^2y})$.

can you pls help me, i have approaches but I don't get continue

Comment: In the hint, notice the $y^{-k}$ is being multiplied by $f$ and $i/c$, and that $|i/c| = 1/c$.

Comment: and what does that bring me

Answer (score 2):

Let $f$ be a weight $k$ modular form for $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$. Let $\mathbb Q\ni x=\frac ac$ with $a,c\in\mathbb Z$, and
$$\gamma=\begin{pmatrix}d&0\\ -c&a\end{pmatrix}\in SL(2,\mathbb Z).$$
In fact, $\gamma$ is just the inverse of $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ with $b=0$. The relation $f|_k\gamma=f$ for $\tau=x+iy$ then reads
$$f(\tfrac ac+i y)=\frac{1}{(-i c y)^k}f\left(-\tfrac dc+\tfrac{  ad}{c^2 y}i\right).$$
The limit $y\downarrow0$ of the second factor is a constant,
$$\lim_{y\downarrow0}f\left(-\tfrac dc+\tfrac{i  ad}{c^2 y}\right)=\lim_{y\uparrow\infty}f\left(-\tfrac dc+\tfrac{  ad y}{c^2 }i\right)=\mathcal O(1).$$
Therefore, the rhs diverges as
$$\lim_{y\downarrow0}f(\tfrac ac+i y)=\mathcal O(y^{-k}).$$

Comment: Can you describe me the last two arguments

Comment: In the second to last equation, you can study the limit $y\uparrow \infty$ of a function $g(y)$ instead of the limit $y\downarrow 0$ of $g(\tfrac1y)$ (the reason for this you can find in any analysis textbook). The second equality is the first equation in your question. The last equation combines the limit, and for small $y>0$ it diverges as $y^{-k}$. The prefactors are not relevant. Perhaps you are confused about the [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).